# Правило наименования моделей laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как назвать имя модели для таблицы "users_transactions" в Laravel?
Правильнее будет назвать: UserTransaction? или UsersTransaction? или UserTransactions?

Comment: Я создаю директорию Users и туда ложу класс Transactions. Но можно и так и так.

Answer (score 4):

Сами разработчики Laravel говорят создавать таблицы в множественном числе, а модели в единичном, тогда в моделях не нужно будет указывать таблицу, фреймворк найдет её сам исходя из названия модели, если укажите не по их правилам - тогда нужна будет явно указать название таблицы.

В вашем случае будет правильно:

Название таблицы: `user_transactions`

Название модели: `UserTransaction`

Answer (score 0):

Можно предоставить связывание названия модели и таблицы самому фреймворку. Если выполнить эту команду:

```
php artisan make:model UserTransaction -m
```

то в проекте будут созданы и файл с классом модели, и файл с миграцией для таблицы, название которой будет соответствовать правилам Laravel (`user_transactions`).